# SQL Update with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have a table of records, which has a self-relationship.

Additionally - to make searching easier - I have a flag which determines that a record has been referenced and hence that row is now "obsolete" and is only there for audit purposes:

```
CREATE TABLE Records
(
  RecordID INT(5) NOT NULL,
  Replaces INT(5) NULL,
  Obsolete INT(1) NOT NULL
)
```

`RecordID` is the PK, `Replaces` links to a previous RecordID which has now been replaced, and `Obsolete` is redundant information which just says that another record has replaced this one. It just makes searching a lot easier. The table is very large. These are just 3 of the columns.

The only problem is: there was a typo in one of the queries in the system so for a small set of rows, the Obsolete value was not set to 1 (true).

This query will show all the records with Obsolete equal to 0 which should be equal to 1:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM Records AS rec1
LEFT JOIN Records AS rec2
       ON rec1.Replaces = rec2.RecordID
    WHERE rec2.RecordID IS NOT NULL
      AND rec2.Obsolete = 0;
```

Now I need to run an UPDATE to change all those req2.Obsolete from 0 to 1, but I'm not sure how to write a query with an INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an inner join. Since your query already returns the records that need to be updated, just do this:

```
Update Records
set Obsolete=1 where
RecordID in (
 SELECT rec2.RecordID     
        FROM Records AS rec1
LEFT JOIN Records AS rec2
       ON rec1.Replaces = rec2.RecordID
    WHERE rec2.RecordID IS NOT NULL
      AND rec2.Obsolete = 0
)
```

Comment: "You don't need an inner join" -- if your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is semantically equivalent to an `INNER JOIN` then doesn't that make it an inner join?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Records
SET obsolete = 1
WHERE recordID in (
SELECT rec1.recordid
     FROM Records AS rec1
LEFT JOIN Records AS rec2
       ON rec1.Replaces = rec2.RecordID
    WHERE rec2.RecordID IS NOT NULL
      AND rec2.Obsolete = 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this in two steps using a temporary table:

```
-- Create temporary table for holding RecordIDs to be marked as obsolete
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `mark_obsolete` (`RecordID` INT NOT NULL);

-- Insert RecordIDs to mark as obsolete into temp table
INSERT INTO `mark_obsolete` (`RecordID`)
SELECT `rec2`.`RecordID`
FROM
    `Records` AS `rec1`
    INNER JOIN `Records` AS `rec2`
        ON `rec1`.`Replaces` = `rec2`.`RecordID`
WHERE `rec2`.`Obsolete` = 0;

-- Update records using inner join to temp table
UPDATE
    `Records` AS `r`
    INNER JOIN `mark_obsolete` AS `o`
        ON `r`.`RecordID` = `o`.`RecordID`
SET `r`.`Obsolete` = 1;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE `mark_obsolete`;
```

Note that using a `LEFT JOIN` with `WHERE rec2.RecordID IS NOT NULL` is the same as an `INNER JOIN`.

The reason for using a temporary table is to avoid locking issues when updating the same table used in the sub-query.  And it might also give you better performance than using the `IN` clause.